# How to get the numeric value from intent extra String

Tags: java, android

I'm using intent to pass the string value to next Activity where I use getStringExtra to get the Value. The value is is User Contact no. in 10 digit which is in numeric value. when I setText in textview then It display the correct format but when I use intent on onclicklistener to open dialpad then instead of no, some random no. appears and in 4 digit also

Here I use to pass string

```
 intent.putExtra(MOBILE, g.getSellermobile());
```

and I receive it by

```
 tutor_mobile = intent.getStringExtra(MOBILE);
```

when I set it in textview as

```
    TextView contact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tutor_near);
    contact.setText(tutor_mobile);
```

It display correct format eg `9868336847`
but when I use intent to open dialpad as

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+String.valueOf(tutor_mobile)));
             startActivity(intent);
```

I'm using below code to get the mobile no.

```
  etMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_mobile);
 String sellermobile = etMobile.getText().toString();
```

and In class file I have

```
package com.nepalpolice.filmyduniya.maincategory;

public class location {

    public String sellermobile;

    //  public Uri uri;

    public location( String sellermobile) {


        this.sellermobile = sellermobile;


        //   this.uri = uri;
    }

    public String getSellermobile() { return sellermobile;}

    }

}
```

Then in activity I have

```
public static final String MOBILE = "other_mobile";
```

and

```
  intent.putExtra(MOBILE, g.getSellermobile());
```

and in next activity I have

```
 tutor_mobile = intent.getStringExtra(MOBILE); and
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+String.valueOf(tutor_mobile)));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Then random no. in 4 digit appears.

Then in activity I have

Please Help.

Comment: Can you include the code where `tutor_mobile` is declared/defined?

Comment: Do you try to add this line `tutor_mobile = "9868336847"` then observe result?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen pleaes check I have edited the question

Comment: IMO, you don't have to use String.valueOf(), as the tutor_mobile is already a string. Try removing it and directly add tutor_mobile.

Comment: I did it first , and it didn't work so I thought may be this will work  but also it didn't.

Comment: Ok I figured it out..I just replaced tutor_mobile with MOBILE..it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your `tutor_mobile` is a String value, but thr you rearrange it toString:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+String.valueOf(tutor_mobile)));
```

May be it's not a error, but it's strange. And what do you want to display in dialpad?

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "string format number"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("Response", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: It works but I'm passing intent from next activity to this activity ..I have to use that pass value...it is different as per person or user.

Comment: you have  get data string then why you convert to string